# What if we are unsure if we have committed a mistake during salat

Tags: salat

While I am praying namaz i sometimes forget which rakat was I on or whether I have missed sometging or not. Maybe these are from the shaitaan. What to do Then? Should I perform Sajdah-e-suhu or should I leave it?